# getting video width when onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() is fired

Tags: javascript, youtube

I am using Youtube API and I want to get video width and height when onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() is fired in order to resize the iFrame (or the div wrapper) which contains this video.
Thank's for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can resize the container of a video responsively just with css!

Take a look at this page:
http://embedresponsively.com/

Use the css displayed underneath the video.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to this but I don't think it's a response to my problem because I want to retrieve the original width and height